# junit 4 with spring mvc 3.1

Tags: spring-mvc, junit4

I  am new with spring mvc .I have written my dao and now i want to test it .So which framework will be best for testing spring mvc app.

and How to do  testing in spring 3.1 mvc application with testing framework like junit or mockito.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to read [Testing](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.2.x/spring-framework-reference/html/testing.html) in Spring Reference. This covers most of the aspect of testing with with spring framework. Hope this helps.